# Cordova Install errors

Tags: cordova, npm

I'm having some issues trying to install cordova. I already run the command npm install -g cordova, then when I try to check the version of Cordova with the command cordova --version, I get the next error:

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'content-disposition'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> 

    (C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\
    express\lib\utils.js:16:26)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

Help please, thanks

Comment: You are probably using one of those newer and buggier NodeJS versions, switch back to the reliable ones like latest from the 4.x branch.